# Expected number of people who are hospitalized, given the total loss due to hospitalization

Tags: probability, expectation, actuarial-science

**NOTE:** I'm currently a high school senior planning to take the Actuary P-Exam next year. I've posted one question from **a past P-Exam down below** that I had trouble with. If anyone has any additional resources or books that help prepare for this exam, that would be greatly appreciated.

The question is as follows:

> A driver and a passenger are in a car accident. Each of them independently has probability $0.3$ of being hospitalized. When a hospitalization occurs, the loss is uniformly distributed on $[0,1]$. When two hospitalizations occur, the losses are independent.
>
> Calculate the expected number of people in the car who are hospitalized, given that the total loss due to hospitalizations from the accident is less than $1$.
>
> (A) $0.510$
>
> (B) $0.534$
>
> (C) $0.600$
>
> (D) $0.628$
>
> (E) $0.800$

**The answer is (B).**

When attempting this question, I first calculated the probability of $0$ hospitalizations occurring, $1$ hospitalization occurring, and $2$ hospitalizations occurring.

$$P(0) = (0.7)^2$$
$$P(1) = 2(0.3)(0.7)$$
$$P(2) = (0.3)^2$$

Then I tried to calculate the expected value:

$$E(X) = 0*P(0) + 1*P(1) + 2*P(2) = 2(0.3)(0.7) + 2(0.3)^2$$

However, this led me nowhere to the answer.

Could someone point me in the right direction in getting a solution to this problem? Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Hmmm, the problem seems to be with the combination of continuous  random variable with discrete random variable. Sorry I am not expert at probability. But perhaps you can remove a chunk of the probability distribution then normalize the remaining distribution?

Answer (score 2):

Let $N$ be the random number of hospitalizations, so $N \in \{0, 1, 2\} \sim \operatorname{Binomial}(n = 2, p = 0.3)$.  Let $L$ be the total loss of all hospitalizations.  We are asked to find $$\operatorname{E}[N \mid L \le 1] = \sum_{k=0}^2 k \Pr[N = k \mid L \le 1],$$ by the definition of expectation.  Now we must compute the conditional probabilities.  $$\Pr[N = k \mid L \le 1] = \frac{\Pr[L \le 1 \mid N = k]\Pr[N = k]}{\Pr[L \le 1]},$$ by Bayes' theorem.  We know that $$\Pr[N = k] = \binom{2}{k} (0.3)^k (0.7)^{2-k},$$ and: $$\begin{align*} \Pr[L \le 1 \mid N = 0] &= 1, \\ \Pr[L \le 1 \mid N = 1] &= 1, \\ \Pr[L \le 1 \mid N = 2] &= \int_{x=0}^1 \int_{y=0}^{1-x} \, dy \, dx = \frac{1}{2}. \end{align*}$$  Therefore, $$\Pr[L \le 1] = 1(0.7)^2 + 1(2)(0.3)(0.7) + \frac{1}{2}(0.3)^2 = \frac{191}{200},$$ and the rest of the calculation is straightforward:  $$\operatorname{E}[N \mid L \le 1] = \frac{\Pr[L \le 1 \mid N = 1]\Pr[N = 1] + 2 \Pr[L \le 1 \mid N = 2]\Pr[N = 2]}{\Pr[L \le 1]}.$$

---

*Mathematica* code to compute the empirical expectation for $10^6$ simulations:

```
Mean[Last /@ Select[{Total[RandomVariate[UniformDistribution[{0, 1}], #]], #} & /@ RandomVariate[BinomialDistribution[2, 0.3], 10^6], First[#] <= 1 &]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Find the probability of loss given hospitalizations.

$P(X=x|h=0) = \delta (x)$

$X_{h=1} \tilde{}  U(0,1)$, or

$P(X=x|h=0) = \begin{cases} 1 &\text{ for } 0\leq x \leq 1 \\ 
0 &\text{ otherwise.} \end{cases}$

$P(X=x|h=2) = \begin{cases}
x &\mbox{ if } 0 \leq x \leq 1\\
1-x &\mbox{ if } 1 \leq x \leq 2 \\
0 &\mbox{ otherwise}
\end{cases} $

Now, you want to find $E[h|X<1]$. Okay, what is $P(h|X)$?

$P(h|X) = \frac{P(h,X)}{P(X)} = \frac{P(X|h)P(h)}{\sum_{h \in \{0,1,2\} } P(X|h)P(h)}$.

You already know that $P(h=0)=0.7^2$, $P(h=1)=2(0.3)(0.7)$, and $P(h=2)=0.3^2$. Can you solve for $P(h|X)$ now?

Comment: What do I do with $U(0,1)$?

Comment: I wrote out the expression for U(0,1). Can you try to get some expression/values for $P(h|X)$?